# How can I get the value of [approve "] [" id "] with swiftjson?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3, swifty-json

my friends have encountered a problem. Thank you very much for reading
I use the library swiftyJson  and my swift version is 3

```
{
"result": [
    {
        "id": 427,
        "tracking_code": "4271547641283",
        "payments": "45,000",
        "items": [
            {
                "service": "خدمات آرایش کودک کات (اصلاح مو) شستشو و حالت دهی مو",
                "price": "25000.00",
                "total_price": "25000.00",
                "quantity": "1"
            },
            {
                "service": "خدمات آرایش کودک کات (اصلاح مو و سشوار)",
                "price": "20000.00",
                "total_price": "20000.00",
                "quantity": "1"
            }
        ],
        "address": "تهران سعادت آباد خیابان ابریشم ۴ شرق پ ۱۲",
        "postal_code": "۳۴۵۶۷۲۴۳8",
        "phone": "09381576103",
        "status": "در انتظار پرداخت",
        "online": "1",
        "approved": "درخواست تایید شده است",
        "rate": null,
        "approved_user": {
            "id": 36,
            "image": "http://www.tipchin.com/assets/uploads/user/medium/84afccebc7ef8e9cf3cd2066036cefc6.jpg",
            "name": "tets",
            "family": "تستی",
            "birthday": "1373/9/27",
            "services": [
                "پیرایش مو، ابرو و اصلاح صورت",
                "خدمات آرایش داماد",
                "خدمات آرایش کودک",
                "گریم و متعادل سازی چهره",
                "خدمات ویژه مو",
                "خدمات پوست و زیبایی",
                "میکرو اسکالپ",
                "نگهداری و زیبایی مو"
            ]
        },
        "date_request": "۱۳۹۷/۱۰/۲۹ ۰۴:۲۰",
        "created_at": "۱۳۹۷/۱۰/۲۶ ۱۵:۵۱"
    }
]
}
```

How can I get the value of [approved_user"][" id "] with swifty json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I hope you have json in SwiftyJson format `JSON`

```
let json = JSON(data)
```

---

Ok, so first you have to get array for key `"result"`

```
json["result"]
```

then we need some element from this array, so we have to specify index of it

```
json["result"][0]
```

then we need object for key `"approved_user"`

```
json["result"][0]["approved_user"]
```

and now we can get its id property

```
json["result"][0]["approved_user"]["id"]
```

---

So:

```
let id = json["result"][0]["approved_user"]["id"].intValue
```

---

Anyway, I would suggest you to start using Swift 4+, since you can learn with `Codable` and then your iOS programming life will be much easier. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you move to Swift 4 since it has a very powerful API's provided by Apple i.e Codable's. To answer your question to parse the response with SwiftyJson Please Have look into Coding Example.

CodingExample:

```
  let response = """
{
"result": [
{
"id": 427,
"tracking_code": "4271547641283",
"payments": "45,000",
"items": [
{
"service": "خدمات آرایش کودک کات (اصلاح مو) شستشو و حالت دهی مو",
"price": "25000.00",
"total_price": "25000.00",
"quantity": "1"
},
{
"service": "خدمات آرایش کودک کات (اصلاح مو و سشوار)",
"price": "20000.00",
"total_price": "20000.00",
"quantity": "1"
}
],
"address": "تهران سعادت آباد خیابان ابریشم ۴ شرق پ ۱۲",
"postal_code": "۳۴۵۶۷۲۴۳8",
"phone": "09381576103",
"status": "در انتظار پرداخت",
"online": "1",
"approved": "درخواست تایید شده است",
"rate": null,
"approved_user": {
"id": 36,
"image": "http://www.tipchin.com/assets/uploads/user/medium/84afccebc7ef8e9cf3cd2066036cefc6.jpg",
"name": "tets",
"family": "تستی",
"birthday": "1373/9/27",
"services": [
"پیرایش مو، ابرو و اصلاح صورت",
"خدمات آرایش داماد",
"خدمات آرایش کودک",
"گریم و متعادل سازی چهره",
"خدمات ویژه مو",
"خدمات پوست و زیبایی",
"میکرو اسکالپ",
"نگهداری و زیبایی مو"
]
},
"date_request": "۱۳۹۷/۱۰/۲۹ ۰۴:۲۰",
"created_at": "۱۳۹۷/۱۰/۲۶ ۱۵:۵۱"
}
]
}

"""
 let json = JSON(data)       
 let id = json["result"][0]["approved_user"]["id"].intValue
```